# JS Array of Objects filter out values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hi I've been struggling to filter an array of objects.

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arrayOne = [
    {userid: 111, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 222, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 333, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 444, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 555, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
]
```

And an array like this:

```
Const arrayTwo = [
    111,
    333
}
```

I want to create an updated arrayOne (arrayThree) like this (remove userid's found in arrayTwo)

```
const arrayThree = [
    {userid: 222, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 444, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
    {userid: 555, photo: “blahblahlbha”}
]
```

I've tried a few variations of below without much luck

```
const arrayThree = Object.keys(arrayOne).filter((k) => !arrayTwo.includes(arrayOne[k].userid))
```

thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Object.keys()`. Just use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

And also there are some syntax errors in your code.

- You need to add commas (`,`) between array items in `arrayOne`.
- The quotation marks (`"`) are not actually quotation marks, you need 
  to convert them as well.
- You need to close the `arrayTwo` with square bracket (`]`), not with 
  curly brace (`}`).

```js
const arrayOne = [
    {userid: 111, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 222, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 333, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 444, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 555, photo: "blahblahlbha"}
]

const arrayTwo = [
    111,
    333
]

const arrayThree =  arrayOne.filter(item => !arrayTwo.includes(item.userid))

console.log(arrayThree)
```

Comment: @Soham You're right. But the question is about filtering out items based on another array. Maybe OP can use a polyfill with `Array.indexOf()` method, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result using `reduce` function. Iterate over `arrayOne`, check if `userid` of current object is present in `arrayTwo`, if not present, add current object to new array that will be returned by `reduce` function

```js
const arrayOne = [
    {userid: 111, photo: 'blahblahlbha'},
    {userid: 222, photo: 'blahblahlbha'},
    {userid: 333, photo: 'blahblahlbha'},
    {userid: 444, photo: 'blahblahlbha'},
    {userid: 555, photo: 'blahblahlbha'},
];

const arrayTwo = [
    111,
    333
];

const arrayThree = arrayOne.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!arrayTwo.includes(curr.userid)) {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(arrayThree);
```

Comment: IMO, This is an ideal use case for `Array#filter`.

Comment: @Rayon agreed but as another person posted a solution using `filter` function, i posted another approach to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` and `includes`. (There are some typos in data, fixed as below)

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { userid: 111, photo: "blahblahlbha" },
  { userid: 222, photo: "blahblahlbha" },
  { userid: 333, photo: "blahblahlbha" },
  { userid: 444, photo: "blahblahlbha" },
  { userid: 555, photo: "blahblahlbha" }
];

const arrayTwo = [111, 333];

const arrayThree = arrayOne.filter(({ userid }) => !arrayTwo.includes(userid));

console.log(arrayThree);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
const arrayOne = [
    {userid: 111, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 222, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 333, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 444, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 555, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
]

const arrayTwo = [
    111,
    333
];

const arrayThree = arrayOne.filter(item => !arrayTwo.includes(item.userid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many used `includes` method of Array which doesn't support in Internet Explorer so using `indexOf` is a better option always.

```
const arrayOne = [
    {userid: 111, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 222, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 333, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 444, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
    {userid: 555, photo: "blahblahlbha"},
]

const arrayTwo = [
    111,
    333
];

const arrayThree = arrayOne.filter(item => arrayTwo.indexOf(item.userid) < 0);

console.log(arrayThree)
```